# monitor Apache current downloaing files

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, monitoring, cpanel

I'm using Apache to allow users of my application to download required updates.

I want to know are there any methods to understand which files are currently downloading and which IP is downloading which file?

As long as I know all files are downloaded by `GET` command in HTTP protocol however I don't know if there is any commands or utility to let me know the download status. Something like what `pure-ftpwho` do for clients of `pure-ftpd`.
My server is Centos 7.9 with Cpanel/WHM installed on it.

Comment: do you run some PHP or other script on this Apache? All of them should get information from GET request about user's IP, etc. Eventually you should have information in Apache log file.

Comment: Read `man lsof`.